# Identify Floor tiles on the great pyramid of meereen

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify the floor tiles used in [The Great Pyramid of Meereen](https://www.flickr.com/photos/143292376@N08/29221977631/in/album-72157671891070860/). I looked at all the 2x2 decorated tiles on bricklink and couldn't find them.

[image: floor tile photo]

Comment: Even I am struggling to find these. The closest I can get is with part 3068bpb0893, which has the word grid in its name.  Those other parts would be considered grids too if we look at what I found and what the MOC has, but if we type "tile 2x2 grid" into bricklink we do not see those other parts so I think they are custom parts.

Comment: This is, most likely, custom print. There are plates on the right side with similarly colored print that overlap on two elements - one of the dashes is split between two elements. This is not something I saw TLG do. It also makes me think that elements have prints that are too close to the edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are indeed quite beautiful tiles but unfortunately not official LEGO decals.

I believe they are his own original custom designs, as in another MOC for Portal 2 which can be seen at [LEGO IDEAS](https://ideas.lego.com/projects/d7feb677-5b5d-4a73-b146-2fe2c6eaeb50) he does confirm that he uses his own custom decals.

> I based my design on the amazing 2012 Lego Cuusoo “Thinking with
> Portals” by Brickthing. I took his original design and added elements
> from Lego Dimensions and my own twist **with custom decals** and details
> from the Portal games.

There seem to be many [more examples](https://www.flickr.com/photos/143292376@N08/30587722755/in/album-72157675708925535/) on that Flickr account.

[image]